# Pretty-printing physical quantities with automatic scaling of SI prefixes

Tags: python, units-of-measurement

I am looking for an elegant way to pretty-print physical quantities with the most appropriate prefix (as in `12300 grams` are `12.3 kilograms`). A simple approach looks like this:

```
def pprint_units(v, unit_str, num_fmt="{:.3f}"):
    """ Pretty printer for physical quantities """
    # prefixes and power:
    u_pres = [(-9, u'n'), (-6, u'µ'), (-3, u'm'), (0, ''),
              (+3, u'k'), (+6, u'M'), (+9, u'G')]

    if v == 0:
        return num_fmt.format(v) + " " + unit_str
    p = np.log10(1.0*abs(v))
    p_diffs = np.array([(p - u_p[0]) for u_p in u_pres])
    idx = np.argmin(p_diffs * (1+np.sign(p_diffs))) - 1
    u_p = u_pres[idx if idx >= 0 else 0]

    return num_fmt.format(v / 10.**u_p[0]) + " " + u_p[1]  + unit_str

for v in [12e-6, 3.4, .123, 3452]:
    print(pprint_units(v, 'g', "{: 7.2f}"))
# Prints:
#  12.00 µg
#   3.40 g
# 123.00 mg
#   3.45 kg
```

Looking over [units](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/units/) and [Pint](http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), I could not find that functionality. Are there any other libraries which typeset SI units more comprehensively (to handle special cases like angles, temperatures, etc)?

Comment: What should be expected representation for following quantity : `a=4.0` `a = a / 3.0` `print(pprint_units(a, 'g', "{: 7.2f}"))` ? I cannot give an answer without knowing that.

Comment: @Serge: ``pprint_units(4./3, 'g', "{: 7.2f}")`` should result in ``'   1.33 g'``.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have solved the same problem once. And IMHO with more elegance. No degrees or temperatures though.

```
def sign(x, value=1):
    """Mathematical signum function.

    :param x: Object of investigation
    :param value: The size of the signum (defaults to 1)
    :returns: Plus or minus value
    """
    return -value if x < 0 else value

def prefix(x, dimension=1):
    """Give the number an appropriate SI prefix.

    :param x: Too big or too small number.
    :returns: String containing a number between 1 and 1000 and SI prefix.
    """
    if x == 0:
        return "0  "

    l = math.floor(math.log10(abs(x)))
    if abs(l) > 24:
        l = sign(l, value=24)

    div, mod = divmod(l, 3*dimension)
    return "%.3g %s" % (x * 10**(-l + mod), " kMGTPEZYyzafpnµm"[div])
```

[CommaCalc](https://github.com/pacholik/CommaCalc)

Degrees like that:

```
def intfloatsplit(x):
    i = int(x)
    f = x - i
    return i, f

def prettydegrees(d):
    degrees, rest = intfloatsplit(d)
    minutes, rest = intfloatsplit(60*rest)
    seconds = round(60*rest)
    return "{degrees}° {minutes}' {seconds}''".format(**locals())
```

**edit:**

Added dimension of the unit

```
>>> print(prefix(0.000009, 2))
9 m
>>> print(prefix(0.9, 2))
9e+05 m
```

The second output is not very pretty, I know. You may want to edit the formating string.

**edit:**

Parse inputs like `0.000009 m²`. Works on dimensions less than 10.

```
import unicodedata

def unitprefix(val):
    """Give the unit an appropriate SI prefix.

    :param val: Number and a unit, e.g. "0.000009 m²"
    """
    xstr, unit = val.split(None, 2)
    x = float(xstr)

    try:
        dimension = unicodedata.digit(unit[-1])
    except ValueError:
        dimension = 1

    return prefix(x, dimension) + unit
```

Comment: Nice trick of exploiting negative indexes for the prefix string. It took me a moment to figure out that the link to *CommaCalc* is the reference to your original code. Unless somebody points out  a more comprehensive solution (as in dealing with more complex cases as mm²), the bounty is yours.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in using [Pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), check out the [`to_compact`](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/pull/224) method.  This hasn't made it into the documentation, but I think it does what you're looking for!

Here is the implementation of the example from the OP:

```py
import pint
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

for v in [12e-6, 3.4, .123, 3452]:
    print('{:~7.2f}'.format((v * ureg('g')).to_compact()))   

>>> 12.00 ug
>>> 3.40 g
>>> 123.00 mg
>>> 3.45 kg
```

Answer (score 2):

The `decimal` module can help. Morover it prevents bad float rounding.

```
import decimal
prefix="yzafpnµm kMGTPEZY"
shift=decimal.Decimal('1E24')
def prettyprint(x,baseunit):
    d=(decimal.Decimal(str(x))*shift).normalize()
    m,e=d.to_eng_string().split('E')    
    return m + " " + prefix[int(e)//3] + baseunit

print(prettyprint (12300,'g'))
>>>> '12.3 kg'
```

it can be tuned to manage format.